# in/on with dmy dates

Tags: prepositions, dates

When writing dates in prose in the dmy format (29 March 2014), is the correct preposition "in" or "on". I'm seeing it with "in" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flotilla_%28video_game%29), but that construction is foreign to me.

> It was released **in 29 March 2010** on Steam for Microsoft Windows, and **in 25 March 2010** on Xbox Live Indie Games for the Xbox 360.

"On" would seem to make more sense, from what I know. Verdict?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*On* is the only correct preposition here. *In* is not used to indicate a specific date, no matter what the format.

If you look at the edit history of the Wikipedia page, though, you’ll see that there was originally no date. It originally read:

> It was released **in February 2010** for Microsoft Windows, and **in March 2010** for Xbox Live.

Since this is not a specific date, but rather a period of time, *in* (meaning ‘during the course of’) is the correct preposition in the original text.

Someone later added the dates and forgot to change the preposition. The [user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aHahc21) who added the dates speaks Spanish as his first language, a language that makes a similar distinction; so it almost has to be an oversight. No other changes were made in the edit that introduced the dates, so it was probably just a quick’n’dirty fix.

Comment: The edit in question being [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Flotilla_%28video_game%29&diff=601596793&oldid=601596573), and by a non-native speaker from Venezuela, mind you.

Comment: Jinx, @RegDwigнt! Was just addressing that as you were typing. Spanish would make a similar distinction (_en febrero_ for the month but simply _el 26 de febrero_ with no preposition for the date), so I don’t think the non-nativeness plays a big part here.

Comment: Yeah, just saying. (Plus I do speak some Spanish, so that wasn't quite my point; whether or not Spanish makes the distinction is a red herring because that says nothing about whether *English* makes it. In other words, as a non-native speaker I might well think that English uses *in* for everything, regardless of what my mother tongue does. I would guess you are right, but it's hard to be sure short of asking Hahc21.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt, true … but I’d say a more logical and common approach if you don’t know for sure how a foreign language does something would be to assume that it does it the _same_ way as your own language, rather than in some other way. :-)

Comment: Something was wrong on the Internet, but I have just fixed it. ;-)